# Inheritance and join in symfony and doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with inheritance in symfony2 and doctrine. I have a class A and a sub class B. I have a other class C which has a collection of B. I do a join between C and B but I would like to add a constrainst on this join for exemple I would like to get only the results that have less than one month on the collection of B for each C object. But the field "date" is on the A table, so when I do my join :

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
          $qb->leftJoin('d.Cobject', 'c')
          ->leftJoin('c.Bcollection', 'b');
```

The join between A and B is implicit and I would like to add a constraint on this join. How I can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to totally figure out your problem but the following idea could help you.

```
public function yourFunction() {

    $gap = new \DateTime('-30days');

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->leftJoin('d.Cobject', 'c');

    if (d.date <= $gap) {
        $qb->leftJoin('c.Bcollection', 'b');
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Cheers